# How to change ordering on multiple columns in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I am trying to display a list of names in crystal reports in multiple columns only if there are enough names that it would split into multiple pages otherwise. I want the ordering to be "across then down" when it's in two columns, otherwise if there aren't enough names, just display a single column of names in order.

The problem I'm having is that the ordering is off when it's in two columns, it goes like:

```
A - F
B - G
C
D
E
```

But I want it to be like:

```
A - B
C - D
E
F
G
```

And for only a small group that fits on one page, like this:

```
A
B
C
```

I have "Format with Multiple Columns" in the "Common" tab, and "Down and then Across" on the Layout tab.

Answer (score 0):

Crystal doesn't have dynamic expression option for 'Printing direction' so you must commit to either 'Across then Down' or 'Down than Across'.

As a way around that, you can insert to subreports, each with a different choice for that property.  Then, suppress one and show the other based on the number of records.

Comment: Thank you, I was afraid it was not easy. I will try with a subreport.